# A react native project installation error

Tags: node.js, macos, react-native, npm

am trying to `install` a new react native project on my computer, but i've got many errors:

node version: 11.13

```
npm WARN deprecated react-navigation-stack@1.10.3: This version of React Navigation Stack is no longer supported. Please upgrade to 2.x.x. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/upgrading-from-3.x#react-navigation-stack for instructions.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 1> 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > dtrace-provider@0.8.8 install /Users/ayb/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f8fd3d76/node_modules/dtrace-provider
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep   ACTION binding_gyp_ndtp_target_build_ndtp .
npm ERR! prepareGitDep   TOUCH Release/obj.target/ndtp.stamp
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/ayb/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f8fd3d76/node_modules/fsevents
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > node install.js
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
npm ERR! prepareGitDep   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
npm ERR! prepareGitDep   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /Users/ayb/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f8fd3d76/node_modules/core-js
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > detox@14.9.2 postinstall /Users/ayb/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f8fd3d76/node_modules/detox
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > node scripts/postinstall.js
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep /Users/ayb/Library/Detox/ios/e58101f483e2f39c2622541a36b54cd597701868 was found, but could not find Detox.framework inside it. This means that the Detox framework build process was interrupted.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep          deleting /Users/ayb/Library/Detox/ios/e58101f483e2f39c2622541a36b54cd597701868 and trying to rebuild.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep Extracting Detox sources...
npm ERR! prepareGitDep Building Detox.framework from /Users/ayb/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f8fd3d76/node_modules/detox/ios_src...
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 2> npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! prepareGitDep child_process.js:658
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     throw err;
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     ^
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep Error: Command failed: /Users/ayb/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f8fd3d76/node_modules/detox/scripts/build_framework.ios.sh
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:655:13)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ayb/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f8fd3d76/node_modules/detox/scripts/postinstall.js:2:27)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:12)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN @react-native-community/geolocation@2.0.2 No repository field.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! detox@14.9.2 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall.js`
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! Failed at the detox@14.9.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! premature close
```

Comment: Up topic ^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post the solution, while i don't need detox at the moment of npm i,
I've disabled it :

> export DETOX_DISABLE_POSTINSTALL=1

Answer (score 0):

Upload your dependencies:

Globally:

**npm install**

Or one at a time:

**npm install name-of-the-package**

You can also substitute install for upgrade